# How to read input numbers separated with spaces from command line c++

Tags: c++

I'v got below code:

```
    std::cin >> N >> T;
    std::vector<int> width;

    for (int w = 0; w < N; w++)
    {
        int tmp;
        std::cin >> tmp;

        width.push_back(tmp);
    }
```

If I put `3 2 3 4` as inputs in console, it separates by white space and stores as a vector array.

My question is how is it able to read integer values in `cin` separated by spaces? I would have thought you should be doing `std::cin >> tmp` input four times?

Comment: You should input it as a string first and then extract the int's from there.

Comment: Your question is how to read integers from `std::cin`, and the integers should be separated by whitespace, is that correct? But that's what your program is already doing?

Comment: You said `N` was 3, then loop `N` times, so you take five inputs, but only give four.

Comment: The input for N and T is 8 and 5 respectively. It is actually getting integers separated by whitespace. I just wanted to understand how it works that way

Comment: You might want to read more about [`std::basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), and the two [input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) [operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the following?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.reserve( std::max( 0, argc - 1 ) );

   for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) v.push_back( std::atoi( argv[i] ) );

   //...
}
```